# Replace number with number and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace number with special characters and numbers from a string.

Ex."3 6 8 47" and expected output is " $3 $6 $8 $47 ".

I can use replace method and implemented like below:

```
var content = "1 3 4";
content = content.replace(/1/g, " $1 ");
console.log(content); // $1 3 4
```

Here, I can replace only one number and I do want to write for each number.

Or I can use split method and add $ to each items of array and join.

I'm looking for some generic replace method to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @Alice: No. This is different question. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\d+` to match one or more digits. Inside replacement part, `$&` will refer to the matched string. As `$` has special meaning in regex replacement part, to show `$` as literal, you need to use `$$`.

```
.replace(/\d+/g, '$$$&')
```

```js
console.log('1 2 3'.replace(/\d+/g, '$$$&'));
```

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But input can be any length., how to fix that?

Comment: It will work with input of any length

Comment: @RanjitKumar The regex already covers numbers of any length (except zero)?

Comment: I got it.. Awesome.. Thanks all..

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the callBack of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function if you want. It would give you a provision to modify the matched string even more.

```
let replaced = "3 6 8 47".replace(/\d+/g, (str) => ("$" + str));
```